# Sphinx with autodoc "duplicate object description" Warning when grouping members into separate files

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I have some functions in a module which I would like to break up into two groups in my documentation. I have three files:

**my_mod.rst**

```
my_mod
======
.. automodule:: my_mod
   :no-members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   my_mod/group1
   my_mod/group2
```

**group1.rst**

```
group1
======

.. automodule:: my_mod
   :members: add, subtract
```

**group2.rst**

```
group2
======

.. automodule:: my_mod
   :members: multiply, divide
```

I have to use `.. automodule:: my_mod` in each. In `my_mod.rst` so it displays the module docstring and in the other files to identify the `:members:` that I want to be displayed. However, this causes multiple errors when generating the HTML files, like:

```
/pathto/my_mymod.rst:2: WARNING: duplicate object description of my_mod, other instance in my_mod/group1, use :noindex: for one of them
```

If I add `:noindex:` though, I can no longer link to these functions from elsewhere in the documentation so that is not a solution for me.

Can I avoid these error messages without losing any functionality? Also, this seems to be working as I hoped (except for the error messages), but are there any potential pitfalls to referencing the same module multiple times?

Comment: Why did you indent `toctree`, and place it below the module you want to autodoc? I think it should be dedented and above the module.

Comment: @StevePiercy I'll agree with the indent being unnecessary, but I want the `toctree` below the module docstring so that is why it is ordered that way.

Comment: Have you tried following the warning's advice, then [cross-reference arbitrary locations with `:ref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role)? You might also try using the [`index` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive-index) to ensure it appears in your documentation's index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to use `autofunction`.

```
group1
======

.. currentmodule:: my_mod

.. autofunction:: add
.. autofunction:: subtract
```

and

```
group2
======

.. currentmodule:: my_mod

.. autofunction:: multiply
.. autofunction:: divide
```